# How can i prove that this language is not turing-recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines

I'm having difficulty understanting how can i prove that

L = { w | w0 is the representation of a turing machine M with input {0, 1} and M don't accept w }
is not turing-recognizable

The solution I have is by contradictio.

1. Reduce w0 to w
2. Suppose a TM M', L(M') = L
3. Suppose that w' ∈ L
4. w' is the representation of a turing machine
5. If w' ∈ L then w' ∉ L is false

I can't understand step 4, why w' is the representation of a turing machine?

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @D.W. I edited the question. The question is not in english and it is a little difficult to translate

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of $L$.  You are told that $w' \in L$; what does that mean?  Based on the definition of $L$, this tells you something about $w'$.